# I get a black screen trying to boot Live CD on MacBook Pro

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, macbook, macbook-pro

I've been trying to boot into Ubuntu using both a DVD and a USB Stick. They both work on my desktop computer, but not on my MacBook Pro (8,2). I can get them to show up in the boot menu, and I get to an ASCII menu where I can try Ubuntu, go straight to installation, or check for defects (there's a 4th option I can't remember). But when I choose to try Ubuntu, it just goes to a black screen. I can hear the DVD reading for a few minutes, then it stops. If I hit enter, it starts reading from the DVD again. This makes be think it's booting, but the display drivers aren't working. What can I do?

Comment: Did the posted answer fix your question?

Comment: It's been so long I can't remember. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

It's a fairly common problem with dual card gfx card Macbooks on Linux.

It's usually caused by the fact that the computer has a discrete and integrated gfx card. And improperly uses the card that is not currently connected to the display panel.

The problem and a solution is mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134342/which-iso-image-do-i-need-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-macbook-pro-so-that-it-bo)

Comment: Does this still apply to 18.10? I have the same problem.