# CLOSED - OS X Yosemite - Live USB - Black screen when trying ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi, live-usb, mac

First of all, I have a Macbook Pro mid 2009 with Intel Core 2 duo running OS X Yosemite (8Gb of ram, 500Gb SSD), I downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso and I use a 4Gb USB stick

Here is what I'm trying to do:
As I have an issue with a hard drive (EXT format) from a Synology NAS, I'm trying to access this hard drive using Ubuntu as mentioned on the Synology FAQ: https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/faq/579).

Here is what I did:
To create a bootable USB stick, I followed the insctructions from ubuntu.com: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx using the ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.

Here is the issue:
When I start my mac and press alt key to show bootable menu, I see two EFI-boot options on the USB stick (I don't know why). For both, when I press Enter I have the error message "could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14" then I have the screen which invites to try ubuntu or to install it. In my case, I just want to try it, so I choose "Try ubuntu without installation" and press Enter. Here happens the black screen.

I don't know how to fix it but help would be really appreciate 'cause I'm trying to retrieve some datas on my hard drive.

Thanks

EDIT: I also tried "install" mode instead of "try" mode -> same behavior. I also tried using ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso -> for both modes, "install" or "try", I get the error "i8042 no controller found" and screen freezes...

EDIT 2: I also tried external hard drive instead of USB stick -> same behaviors

CLOSED: I decided to close this post 'cause finally, using Live DVD of Ubuntu and rEFInd, I succeed the installation.

Comment: What do you mean "two UEFI"? The UEFI is the thing that runs on your computer to boot operating systems (does same thing as BIOS). Also, about the black screen, have you tried using your brightness keys to make it brighter (maybe it's all the way down for some reason)? There are some known brightness problems with Intel GPUs in Ubuntu 14.04 after all.

Comment: Mac default boot screen shows 3 options: SSD, EFI-boot, and recovery partition. When I put the USB Stick, the boot screen had 2 more options and names of the 2 options are EFI-boot (with usb icon).
I tried brightness keys: unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: What model? 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, or something else?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here with my MBP early 2011.

Comment: Hi @JensWirth, I recommend use of Live DVD but using rEFInd I think you can solve your issue even if you try with USB. Here is a tutorial which helps me: [link](https://github.com/aroman/freya-on-a-mac). Step 4 type ./install.sh --alldrivers (tutorial based on rEFInd v0.8.3, --esp no more available in v0.8.4). Skip steps 6 and 7 (v0.8.4 do it for you). Step 14, make sure to create 2 partitions: one in ext4 format (other dropdown: select "/") and a second in swap "format" (swap partition must be between 1x to 1.5x your RAM).

PS: Tutorial based on Elementary OS but it works for Ubuntu ;)

Comment: @Flvn: Thanks for the hint to use rEFInd. It's a great tool and doing the job well here. Separate from that, I found the fundamental reason and a solution for your problem. This way it works out of the box with an Ubuntu USB stick and my MacBook Pro:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/239711/i-get-a-black-screen-trying-to-boot-live-cd-on-macbook-pro

Comment: Nice to know you succeeded finding a solution for your issue. It would be great if you (instead of marking this as closed), add your own answer and auto-accept it in order to people know your solution thus helping more people. AskUbuntu doesn't work the same as Forums, that's why we can't simply mark as closed and leave the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **This is not a fix for the issue but an alternative.**

I decided to use a Live DVD and rEFind according to this tutorial: [Freya on a Mac](https://github.com/aroman/freya-on-a-mac)

As the rEFInd version used in the tutorial is older than the one I used (v0.8.3 vs. v0.8.4), some steps changed. Here are changes I applicated:

- Step 4: I only type ./install.sh --alldrivers 'cause --esp is no more available in v0.8.4 ([source](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#installsh))
- Steps 6 and 7: I only skip those steps 'cause v0.8.4 do the job for you
- Step 14: I make sure to create 2 partitions: one in ext4 format (other dropdown: select "/") and a second in swap "format" (swap partition must be between 1x to 1.5x your RAM)

Since the second boot on Ubuntu from the rEFInd screen, each time I choose Ubuntu, the load freezes. To fix this issue, I press F2 when I select Ubuntu, then I press again F2 to edit the launch command and I add **nomodeset** at this end of the command.