# What are my graphics option on a AMD hybrid graphics MacBook Pro (8,2)?

Tags: intel-graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics, macbook-pro

Currently I'm running the AMD chip full time with fglrx drivers, and I get OK battery life.  I would like to get another hour or two though, which I feel is quite possible by switching to the Intel HD4000 chip.  In reading the forums I see that it's possible to do via EFI boot, some kernel patches, using both opensource drivers, and vgaswitcheroo.

That isn't quite ideal though.  I'd really like to be using the AMD drivers, but I can't seem to find anywhere (perhaps my google foo is off) how to do this, although I have seen evidence that it is possible (the Ubuntu wiki page on fglrx for example).  I need to be able to switch between both cards, preferably without restarting X and definitely without needing to reboot.  As this is a laptop, I need to be able to run both in power saving (Intel) and with dual displays (as far as I know that will only work with the AMD chip).  Having to restart at least 3 times a day when I go to class and come back to my desk just isn't going to work.

If anyone is willing to take the time to either give me instructions on how to do this (my skill level is higher than n00b, but less than expert... I've recently learned how to build custom kernels, haven't been able to figure out patching yet though).  I have my EFI partition set up, and grub configured, but it doesn't boot.  I get an error along the lines of "unable to read something from hd(0,0)" (I have the exact message written down at my apartment, so I can post that later) however it starts booting after than until it stops (I assume because it can't load the graphics).  Doesn't crash though, as it will shutdown if I push (not hold) the power button.

Bunch of questions here, but it's really just one question and me letting you know where I'm at with things.  Thanks.  Any help or info will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to build any custom kernel for your Macbook 8,2 nowdays.

following these two should suffice for you to get hybrid graphics running properly.

[Install Macbook 8,2 in efi mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134342/which-iso-image-do-i-need-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-macbook-pro-so-that-it-bo)

[To switch between graphics cards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184406/how-to-switch-between-gfx-cards-on-macbook-pro-15-8-2)