# Ubuntu 12.04 does not start on MacBook Pro: Black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 on my MacBook Pro running OSX 10.8 (the laptop itself is brand new as of March 2013, if that tells you something about the model.) However, when I boot Ubuntu, I'm left with a black screen which prints alot of text about starting/stopping services, but does not function as a terminal. It hangs indefinitely at this screen until I shutdown via power button, which causes it to print more text in regards to "unmounting" and "halting."

**Thus far I have completed the following steps:**

1. Installed rEFIt & GPT fdisk on OSX.
2. Created a new partition, installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto that ext4 partition via USB. No issues during installation.

**My boot procedure is the following:**

1. Power button to turn on
2. rEFIt loads, I can select Mac or Linux from a gray screen.
3. I select Linux, sits on a gray screen briefly then loads GRUB.
4. Now on the GRUB menu (maroon/purple screen), I have options to boot "Ubuntu 12.04 Generic" or Mac.
5. I select the first option, being the default Ubuntu, and it begins loading.
6. This is where it hangs: black screen with some text output. It lists operations it performed followed by "[ OK ]". There is one "[ FAIL ]" listed for an audio related service (I don't think this is the issue.)

**EDIT: Here are the last 3 lines printed when the computer hangs:**

```
Starting Userspace bootsplash... [OK]
Starting LightDM Display Manager... [OK]
Stopping Userspace Bootsplash... [OK]
_
```

(The '_' is a blinking text cursor that does not accept user input.)

Am I looking at a hardware/driver issue? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicated: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/62483)

Comment: Similar but not the same. That post is related to totally black screen, which isn't my issue. I did try what was suggested down the post, by changing "quiet splash $vt_handoff" to "nomodeset_$vt_handoff", to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months, I don't really have a 'fix' to offer for this specific problem.

However, I did re-attempt the install using 13.04, and rEFInd instead of rEFIt, and I was able to load up Ubuntu smoothly on the very same Macbook Pro Retina. Follow [these](http://randomtutor.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/installing-ubuntu-1304-on-retina.html) instructions instead, and you'll likely have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue with several dual card Macbooks & Linux
check out the solution proposed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134342/which-iso-image-do-i-need-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-macbook-pro-so-that-it-bo) post

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a MacBook Pro mid-2010. In my case the screen would go completely black after showing some boot messages; also was not responsive to keyboard. I was able to fix the problem by removing the NVidia binary driver and switching back to Nouveau. I booted from the install disk and created a chroot environment to uninstall the driver. (For some reason passing 'single' to kernel args didn't work.)