# How to configure UEFI booting on a Macbook 8,2

Tags: vgaswitcheroo, grub-efi

I googled a while on this so let me give you the details, then the questions

- I have a Macbook 8,2 15" with Kubuntu Quantal installed from the MAC+AMD64 Desktop CD image. I removed every MacOS partition on install and created GPT-swap-EXT4(/)-EXT4(/local).
- `lspci | grep VGA` only shows an AMD 6600 Series card, so I guess I'm need to configure EFI-booting to be able switch to the low power Intel card.
- I found a package called `grub-efi-amd64` as well as this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting), the latter seems outdated as it suggest compiling grub 1.99 by hand which is also contained in the package I found.

I would kindly ask for clearification on the following:

- Can I just `apt-get install grub-efi-amd64` or is there more to be done (Only Kubuntu on the machine, so grub will do fine - Does it still need to be "blessed" as per the tutorial).
- Does the package work through it all or do I still have to go through steps 3-7 of the tutorial?
- The GPT partition only has 4 MiB. Do I have to enlarge it?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/287441/different-uses-of-term-efi-partition

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you refer to in your question seems quite outdated.

Grub has had native EFI support since at least 2-3 official standard releases of Ubuntu.

To run your Mac in EFI mode i simply installed [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) then boot the mac on a usb key with the standard ubuntu64, selecting the EFI boot option in refind for the Ubuntu installer.
a more detailed tutorial can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134342/which-iso-image-do-i-need-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-macbook-pro-so-that-it-bo) that also deals with some potential issues.

I use Ubuntu with my Macbook 8,2 15" and successfully switch between the two cards.
I wrote a howto for the actual switching [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184406/how-to-switch-between-gfx-cards-on-macbook-pro-15-8-2)

Comment: Okay, mine is MacBook **Pro** and the problem is same with raring ubuntu and kubuntu amd64 dessktop ISOs. As I see it, rEFInd would boot GRUB which boots Linux. So why should that work whereas booting GRUB directly from EFI gives black screen?

Comment: As the link in the post describes you boot the kernel directly from refind bypassing grub entirely. I've updated the post with a link for a detailed efi install faq answering the black screen issue

Comment: Okay, I just managed to grub boot into raring by disabling the discrete GPU - only to find that you cannot run an external display on the iGPU :-( So you're solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu Raring ISO now offers UEFI installs.

Boot the UEFI installer, GRUB comes up, hit `e` to edit the entry, insert `nomodeset` right after `quiet splash` so your screen doesn't go black, then hit `F10` to boot and your good to go.

Comment: Only to realize: Installer GUI will work, but Live CD mode gives a black screen. Same after install: Screen is on but doesn't show anything.